# Pandas group data until first ocurrence of a pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains accidents of cars, they can be 'L' for light or 'S' for strong:

```
|car_id|type_acc|datetime_acc|
------------------------------
|   1  |    L   | 2020-01-01 | 
|   1  |    L   | 2020-01-05 |
|   1  |    S   | 2020-01-07 |
|   1  |    L   | 2020-01-09 |
|   2  |    L   | 2020-01-04 |
|   2  |    L   | 2020-01-10 |
|   2  |    L   | 2020-01-12 |
```

I would like to get a column that counts until the first 'S' and the divide the number of occurrences between the max and min 'L', so the output is:

```
|car_id|freq_acc|
-----------------
|   1  |    2   | # 4 days (from 1 to 5) / 2 number of 'L' before first 'S'
|   2  |    8   | # 8 days(from 4 to 12) and no 'S'
```

Is such a thing possible? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [np.ptp](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) to compute the *max-min* difference:

```
# find first by S by car_id
df['eq_s'] = df.groupby('car_id')['type_acc'].transform(lambda x: x.eq('S').cumsum())

# compute stats based on previous computation, keeping only the first group
groups = df[df['eq_s'].eq(0)].groupby(['car_id']).agg({'datetime_acc': np.ptp}).reset_index()

# rename
res = groups.rename(columns={'datetime_acc': 'freq_acc'})
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   car_id freq_acc
0       1   4 days
1       2   8 days
```

Before anything make sure that *datetime_acc*, is a datetime column, by doing:

```
df['datetime_acc'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_acc'])
```

The first step:

```
# find first by S by car_id
df['eq_s'] = df.groupby('car_id')['type_acc'].transform(lambda x: x.eq('S').cumsum())
```

will create a new column where the only values of interest are the 0, that is the ones that are before the first *S*. In the second step we only keep those values, and perform a standard [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
# compute stats based on previous computation, keeping only the first group
groups = df[df['eq_s'].eq(0)].groupby(['car_id']).agg({'datetime_acc': np.ptp}).reset_index()
```